# How can a parent hand over a prop to the children it is wrapping?

Tags: reactjs

What would be the best way to handy over a prop-value of the parent to the children? The parent is a reusable component of the library of the project.

```
const count= 500
return (
  <Parent>{children}</Parent>
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `React.Children` and `React.cloneElement` like this :

```
const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
  React.cloneElement(child, { count })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in the parent when rendering children:

```
React.cloneElement(children, props)
```